# PostgreSQL:How to return result of a SELECT statement within a function using PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Here i have following function, but not getting how to return the result.

```
create or replace function f1() returns void as  
$body$  
begin    
    SELECT "Fname",  
        "Lname",   
        count("City" = 'A-B' OR NULL) AS "A-B",  
        count("City" = 'C-D' OR NULL) AS "C-D",  
    FROM "Table1"  
    WHERE  "City" in ('A-B','C-D')  
    GROUP BY 1,2  
    ORDER BY 1,2
```

Comment: When you would to get some result from function, then your function MUST not be VOID function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the return type to `RETURNS TABLE (fieldname type, fieldname type, ...)` and use `RETURN QUERY SELECT ...`.

See [the PL/PgSQL docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html).

Comment: Thank you. But the result is showing in a single column.

Comment: @user3382347 Wild guess: You're using `SELECT my_procedure()` not `SELECT * FROM my_procedure()`.